# How can I initialize an object with a string of package path in Python?

Tags: python, python-import

For example, my package path is `component.sub_fold.package.class_name`. The `component.sub_fold` is the path of my package. The `package` is a file name. The `class_name` is a class name which I want to initialize it. I can initialize an object through

```
from component.sub_fold.package import class_name

obj = class_name()
```

How can I initialize an object through the string `"component.sub_fold.package.class_name"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to programmatically import a module by specifying its name, you could use the [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) module.

```
import importlib

name = 'component.sub_fold.package.class_name'
pkg, symbol = name.rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)

pkg = importlib.import_module(pkg)
obj = getattr(pkg, symbol)()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I finally found my question was associated with another similar questions.